# Vertx and Camel Integration

Tags: apache-camel, vert.x

I'm trying to figure out what the best way to send messages from an Apache Camel route to an external Vert.x event bus.

I have looked at the camel-vertx library and the vertx-camel-bridge, but these libraries appear to be used for communicating between Camel and Vert.x running in the same JVM and I'm not seeing any examples with Camel and Vert.x running separately.

Is my assumption correct? And would ActiveMQ be a good bridge between Vertx and Camel?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Vert.x event bus can be clustered. On one node (A), you can have a pure Vert.x application sending messages. On the other node (B), you can have your Camel application with the Vert.x Camel bridge.

On node A:

```
vertx.eventBus().send("eventbus-address", "a message");
```

On node B:

```
CamelContext camel = new DefaultCamelContext();
OutboundMapping outbound = OutboundMapping
  .fromVertx("eventbus-address")
  .toCamel("stream:out");
CamelBridge.create(vertx, new CamelBridgeOptions(camel)
  .addOutboundMapping(outbound)).start();
```

Comment: I don't understand what about the camel-vertx component and having clustered verticles that use infinispan how i connect them ?

Answer (score 0):

Here my two node

The camel one:

```
   @Override
    public void configure() {
        from("vertx:start.event")
                .log("Message received: ${body}")
                .setBody(constant("xxxx"));
    }
```

The vertx one:

```
public class Publisher extends AbstractVerticle {
@Override
public void start() {
    vertx.setPeriodic(1000, timerId -> {
        vertx.eventBus().request("start.event", UUID.randomUUID().toString(), event -> {
            if (event.succeeded()) {
                System.err.println(event.result().body());
            }
        });
    });
  }
}
```

The vertx verticle is clusterized using this mvn dependencie

```
  <dependency>
        <groupId>io.vertx</groupId>
        <artifactId>vertx-infinispan</artifactId>
        <version>4.4.6</version>
    </dependency>
```

My camel route doesn't receive any message

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is still interested here the camel connection to ISPN:

```
public class CamelVertxRoute {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        CamelContext context = new DefaultCamelContext();

        ClusterManager mgr = new InfinispanClusterManager();
        VertxOptions options = new VertxOptions().setClusterManager(mgr);
        Future<Vertx> vertxFuture = Vertx.clusteredVertx(options);

        vertxFuture.onComplete(res -> {
            if (res.succeeded()) {
                Vertx vertx = res.result();
                VertxComponent vertxComponent = new VertxComponent();
                vertxComponent.setVertx(vertx);
                context.addComponent("vertx", vertxComponent);

                // Ugly but just for demo
                try {
                    context.addRoutes(new RouteBuilder() {
                        @Override
                        public void configure() {
                            from("vertx:start.event")
                                    .log("Message received: ${body}")
                                    .setBody(constant("Response from Camel :)"))
                            ;
                        }
                    });
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    throw new RuntimeException(e);
                }
            } else {
                System.err.println("Err joining ISPN");
            }
        });

        // Define a simple Camel route

        // Start the Camel context
        context.start();

        synchronized (CamelVertxRoute.class) {
            CamelVertxRoute.class.wait();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I have removed the question from your answer, as answers are supposed to do just that: answer the question. See [answer]. If you have a new question, please ask it as such.